# ANOVA with R - inconsistent results

Tags: r

I did an ANOVA in the form `aov(y ~ A + B + C)`.

The results looked fine.  However, I noticed when I changed the order of the variables `aov(y ~ A + C + B)`, the F-Value and P-Value for A, B, C changed.  This was unexpected.

Comment: The default in R is type-I sums of squares which means the order you enter variables into the model matters.  Look at `drop1` or using the `Anova` function in the car package and specifying type=3.

Comment: Thx, that explains it.